# Как изменить стили создаваемые taiga-ui только в конкретном компоненте?

Tags: css, angular

В проекте используется библиотека taiga-ui, и при использовании компонента accordion, тайга добавляет свои внутренние теги с ненужными паддингами. При простой замене через scss стили, они никак не изменяются. Есть ли возможность заменить стили именно в данном компоненте не прибегая к изменению стилей в файлах самой библиотеки?

- *.component.html и *.component.scss

```css
tui-accordion {
  padding: 0 !important;
  tui-accordion-item {
    border-color: var(--tui-base-03) !important;
  }
  .content {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<tui-accordion>
  <tui-accordion-item borders="top-bottom" size="s" *ngFor="let group of notificationsGroups.value">
    {{ group.group }}
    <ng-template tuiAccordionItemContent>
      <div *ngFor="let notification of group.notifications">
        <app-notification [notification]="notification" (removeNotificationEvent)="deleteNotification($event)"></app-notification>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </tui-accordion-item>
</tui-accordion>
```

- HTML и CSS из инспектора

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]